# Явная загрузка DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

В связи с сложностями которые возникают в связи с импортом классов при явном подключении DLL (с помощью winapi), стоит ли его использовать, есть практический смысл? Если да, то в каких случаях это оправданно.

Comment: Что подразумевается под "явным подключением"?

Comment: Имеется в виду LoadLibrary/GetProcaddress? Кто-то использует их для подключения классов из DLL?

Comment: Например, для использования OpenGL на Windows всегда используют загрузку по DLL, потому что у мелкомягких в статической либе только версия только 1.1